# How do I import settings when using DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: django, django-settings

I have a Django project and am using the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for managing each environment settings. I have created different settings files for each environment, however, I'm confused how I can access these settings without having to change the imports in my code. For example, I have this settings directory structure:

```
stats/
    config/
        settings/
            __init__
            base.py
            dev.py
            prod.py
```

`base.py` has all my default settings, include some API keys for third party services. I override these in each environment:

base.py

```
API_KEY  = "default"
```

dev.py

```
from base import *
API_KEY = "dev"
```

prod.py

```
from base import *
API_KEY = "prod"
```

When I start up my server, I use

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=stats.config.settings.dev
```

But how do I access the `API_KEY` without having to change "dev" to "prod" every time I deploy? This is how I currently access the `API_KEY` in my code:

`from stats.config.settings.dev import API_KEY`

I can't seem to find the proper answer to this anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You access your settings via `django.conf.settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code), you're not supposed to import/access them directly

```
from django.conf import settings
settings. API_KEY
```

Comment: Ahhh, I read that during the set up of my different environments but didn't quite make the connection between the two. I tested it out and it's working. Thanks!